# Composer autoloader + slim framework - fatal error: Class 'Slim\Slim' not found?

Tags: php, composer-php, slim, autoloader

How can I use composer autoloader to load slim? I have it a go below,

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Slim\Slim;

Slim::registerAutoloader();

//Instantiate a Slim application:
$app = new Slim();

//Define a HTTP GET route:
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello!";
});

$app->get('/hello/:name/', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

//Run the Slim application:
$app->run();
```

**error:**

> Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Slim' not found in C:...

Any ideas what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to keep slim under ext (as you mentioned here [Slim framework - How to autoload Slim/Slim.php instead of using require?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27826066/1512654)) instead of using it as a composer package, I believe this will work:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "ext/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use ...

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

http://docs.slimframework.com/

Comment: Although implied he also needs to run `composer install` to install it... then the `vendor/autoload.php` will work correctly. Also at that point he wont need to use `\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader()`.